# Cannot place the ChartJs legends on the left

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, chart.js

```
import { Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

const getRandomColor = () => {
    const letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    let color = '#';
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
};

const DoughnutChart = ({ data, label, city }) => {
    const sortedData = [...data].sort((a, b) => b.total - a.total);
    const limitedData = sortedData.slice(0, 5);
    const otherTotal = sortedData.slice(5).reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.total, 0);

    if (sortedData.length > 5) {
        limitedData.push({
            [label]: 'Other',
            total: otherTotal
        });
    }

    const chartData = {
        labels: limitedData.map(item => item[label]),
        datasets: [
            {
                label: '# of Devices',
                data: limitedData.map(item => item.total),
                backgroundColor: limitedData.map(() => getRandomColor()),
                borderColor: limitedData.map(() => getRandomColor()),
                borderWidth: 1,
            },
        ],
    };

    const total = chartData.datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

    const options = {
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                color: '#000000',
                display: true,
                formatter: (value, ctx) => {
                    let percentage = value / total * 100;
                    percentage = percentage.toFixed(2);
                    return `${value} (${percentage}%)`;
                }
            },
        },
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'left',
        },
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Doughnut data={chartData} options={options} plugins={[ChartDataLabels]} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default DoughnutChart;
```

My DoughnutChart.js component does not place it's legends on the left. Here is a screenshot of what is happening.
[image: Doughnut Charts]

What I want to do is that legends (such as AV, AU, AX, AS etc. should be displayed on the left and doughnut chart can be more bigger than it is now.)

```
// Manually configure the Chart.js global defaults.
Chart.defaults.plugins.legend.position = 'left';
```

or

```
    const options = {
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                color: '#000000',
                display: true,
                formatter: (value, ctx) => {
                    let percentage = value / total * 100;
                    percentage = percentage.toFixed(2);
                    return `${value} (${percentage}%)`;
                }
            },
        },
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'left',
        },
    };
```

or

```
    const options = {
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          color: '#000000',
          display: true,
          formatter: (value, ctx) => {
            let percentage = value / total * 100;
            percentage = percentage.toFixed(2);
            return `${value} (${percentage}%)`;
          }
        },
      },
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'left',
        labels: {
          usePointStyle: true,
        },
      },
    };
```

But none of them worked.
What should i do, in order to make them appear on left. I don't want to use custom HTML legend, since it makes the current legends more static and it is not so stylish.

Answer (score 1):

`legend` must be placed inside `options.plugins`, same as `datalabels`.

```
const options = {
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      ...
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'left'
    }      
  }
};
```

For further information, please consult the Chart.js documentation [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html).